# Can we implement auto suggestion in apache solr search box

Tags: spell-checking

> How to use search suggestions in apache solr  input textbox?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Is the search box part of your application?  Have you tried running through the approach in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester?

Comment: thanx peter for quick rply. yes search box is a part of my application. i want to search suggestion during entering the string in search input box. I also tried above link, but not helpfull.

Comment: xml response http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
<str name="command">full-import</str><str name="status">idle</str><str name="importResponse"/><lst name="statusMessages"><str name="Time Elapsed">0:9:52.389</str><str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str><str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str><str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str><str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str><str name="Full Dump Started">2015-10-05 11:04:24</str><str name="Full Import failed">2015-10-05 11:04:24</str></lst></response>

Answer (score 0):

Start here to learn about the three general approaches for autosuggest:  http://blog.trifork.com/2012/02/15/different-ways-to-make-auto-suggestions-with-solr/

This tutorial uses Suggester:  http://solr.pl/en/2010/11/15/solr-and-autocomplete-part-2/

This example uses `facet.prefix`:  http://solr.pl/en/2010/10/18/solr-and-autocomplete-part-1/

Comment: hi peter, my suggeter query null data return.
url : http://localhost:8984/solr/suggest?suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.q=noida&wt=json
and
Response : {"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":10},"command":"build","suggest":{"mySuggester":{"noida":{"numFound":0,"suggestions":[]}}}}

Comment: **solrconfig.xml**
'  <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">Name</str>
    <str name="weightField">Address</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>'

Comment: '  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
  <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>'
**plz tell me, what is the issue**

Comment: If your last comment on your first post is any indication, than your import isn't working (therefore no data in the index to suggest).  Perhaps spend a little time debugging your import, and if still having difficulty, post back with an import-specific question and your `data-config.xml`

Comment: ^^ along with any logging messages you see at the time you try your import ^^

Comment: its working by this url :
'http://localhost:8984/solr/spell?q=secO&suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=xml'
and return the data. is it correct url?